# Upgradability of a smart contract

Tags: upgrade

Is there any smart contract project example that uses proxy contract implementation for upgradability of smart contract in tezos ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my training here and choose what is most appropriated for you

https://github.com/marigold-dev/training-dapp-4